# Delete text in textbox without deleting the textbox on canvas in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js and have IText textboxes on canvas. The user can freely move the textbox around and also edit the text within. How to avoid a textbox being deleted (removed from the canvas) when the user deletes the text using delete key and there's no more text?

Thanks for the response.

```
deleteText(activeObject) {
      var startIndex = activeObject.selectionStart;
      var endIndex = activeObject.selectionEnd;
      if (endIndex > 0 && startIndex != endIndex) {
        var text = activeObject.text;
        var newText =
          text.substring(0, startIndex) +
          text.substring(endIndex + 1, text.length);
        activeObject.set("text", newText);
        this.canvas.fire("object:modified");
      } else {
        this.canvas.remove(activeObject);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code please? So we can help you on what's wrong.

Comment: @DarkIceDust my this is the code.

Comment: `this.canvas.remove(activeObject);` with this code, you are deleting the text object.

Answer (score 0):

have 2 versions of answer

1.Your are deleting textbox using this line of code , try commenting it and see what happens

```js
this.canvas.remove(activeObject);
```

2.Textbox is not being deleted , you can't see it because of white canvas background and emptiness inside textbox, since there is no text , try mousedowning a canvas and select a big area , check if you are able to select your textbox this way